# php preg_match search pattern

Tags: php, html-parsing, preg-match-all

I have a table and would like to get a 2d array (per line and the cell values for each line).
I know that I have to use preg_match but I am not good at creating patterns.

May you help me? Would be veeeeeery nice!!!!

Thank you!!!

Here is my table structure:

```
<table class="maintable">
<tr>
<td class="headtable">
Tag
</td>
<td class="headtable">
Klasse
</td>
<td class="headtable">
Zeit
</td>
<td class="headtable">
Pos
</td>
<td class="headtable">
Lehrer
</td>
<td class="headtable">
Fach
</td>
<td class="headtable">
Raum
</td>
<td class="headtable">
Info
</td>
<td class="headtable">
Art
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="evenrow">
<td class="evencell">
Mo
</td>
<td class="evencell">
05a
</td>
<td class="evencell">
09:45
</td>
<td class="evencell">
3. Stunde
</td>
<td class="evencell">
+TIN (KOL)
</td>
<td class="evencell">
In En
</td>
<td class="evencell">
223
</td>
<td class="evencell">

</td>
<td class="evencell">
Geändert
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="oddrow">
<td class="oddcell">
&nbsp
</td>
<td class="oddcell">
&nbsp
</td>
<td class="oddcell">
10:30
</td>
<td class="oddcell">
4. Stunde
</td>
<td class="oddcell">
+TIN (KOL)
</td>
<td class="oddcell">
In En
</td>
<td class="oddcell">
223
</td>
<td class="oddcell">

</td>
<td class="oddcell">
Geändert
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="evenrow">
<td class="evencell">
&nbsp
</td>
<td class="evencell">
&nbsp
</td>
<td class="evencell">
13:45
</td>
<td class="evencell">
8. Stunde
</td>
<td class="evencell">
+NUS (CRI), WIK
</td>
<td class="evencell">
Comp
</td>
<td class="evencell">
022 INF2, 021 INF1
</td>
<td class="evencell">

</td>
<td class="evencell">
Geändert
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="oddrow">
<td class="oddcell">
&nbsp
</td>
<td class="oddcell">
05b
</td>
<td class="oddcell">
07:55
</td>
<td class="oddcell">
1. Stunde
</td>
<td class="oddcell">
+WEP (SMA)
</td>
<td class="oddcell">
EN
</td>
<td class="oddcell">
121
</td>
<td class="oddcell">

</td>
<td class="oddcell">
Geändert
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No, you don't need to use preg_match.  **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: Use a [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments this is not a good idea to parse HTML using regex.
Anyway, here is how you could achieve it using preg_match_all assuming `$input` contains the input string :

```
<?php

preg_match_all('#<tr[^>]*>(.*?)</tr>#is', $input, $lines);

$result = array();

foreach ($lines[1] as $k => $line) {
    preg_match_all('#<td[^>]*>(.*?)</td>#is', $line, $cell);

    foreach ($cell[1] as $cell) {
        $result[$k][] = trim($cell);
    }
}

var_dump($result);

?>
```